# Round currency/number (jqGrid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have grid, where I input a number, ex. `15.32`.

How can I round this number up to `16.00`?

If I have `16.01`, I want to round it up to `17.00`. The number will always round up.

```
{
    label:'Summ',
    name:'f4',
    index:'f4',
    width:120,
    search: false,
    formatter:'currency',
    formatoptions:{defaulValue:0,thousandsSeparator:' ',decimalPlaces:2,suffix:'$'}
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom formatter for that, that both ceils the number value and suffixes.
For example:

```
// Custom formatter that ceils all number values and suffixes .00$
function myCurrencyFormatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
    if(cellvalue == undefined) return "0.00$";
    else return Math.ceil(cellvalue) + ".00$";
}

{
    label: "Sunm",
    name:'f4',
    index:'f4',
    width:120,
    search: false,
    // Uses the custom formatter
    formatter: myCurrencyFormatter,
}
```

You can try it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mowday/NH498/

Comment: I updated the fiddler version to also handle thousand seperator.

Comment: Thx. I can do it :)
But now...

**f4 = funding*funding_votes/100**
//funding and funding_votes - is a value

And i have next value is "**f5**" where **f5 = f4+total_amoun**
and here i can't see around... i must to write function for everywear i label?

Maybe i can to write only in one and where join the label is output me correct

P.S. Sorry for bad English :((

Comment: No, you can reuse the same function for any currency column by setting the "formatter" option to "myCurrencyFormatter". Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: what i now, for everywear i set **formatter: myCurrencyFormatter** hm... i can't to set question.. i have second question how i can to use this option **defaulValue:0,thousandsSeparator:' ',decimalPlaces:2,suffix:'$'**

Comment: Check the fiddle link, should explain everything in code

Comment: Did it help?
If this answered your original question, would you mind marking it as answered?